# Will Adobe Reader 9.5.3 be offered in partner repository?

Tags: updates, package-management, security, software-sources, adobe-reader

Will there be an Ubuntu package in the Canonical Partner repository for the security update Adobe Reader 9.5.3?

- ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.3/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.3-1_i386linux_enu.deb

Answer (score 0):

`adobereader-enu 9.5.5` is available on  *ppa:berkon/ppa* [Repository](https://launchpad.net/~berkon/+archive/ppa): See.